# React-Router: Import And Use Named URLs

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Is there a formal method for importing my defined routes and redirecting to named patterns within that router from another React component?

Say my routes look like this:

```
# router.cjsx
Routes = require'react-router').Routes
Route = require('react-router').Route

React.renderComponent((
  <Routes location="history">
    <Route handler={App}>
      <Route name="login" handler={LoginComponent} path="/login/" />
    </Route>
  </Routes>
), document.body)
```

And I have a component like this:

```
# my-component.cjsx
React = require('react')

module.exports = React.createClass
  componentDidMount: ->
    # If user is not authenticated, redirect them to the login component
    if not @props.user.isAuthed
       window.location.replace('/login/')  # I WOULD RATHER NOT HARDCODE THIS URL
```

Two questions:

1. Should I be using `window.location.replace()` or some other React-Router method to handle programatic redirects?
2. Is there any way to import the Router and redirect to the named route?

I want to write something like:

```
# my-component.cjsx
MyAppRouter = require('./router').MyRouter  # Should I be exporting this?

window.location.replace(MyAppRouter.login)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can accomplish what you want using `transitionTo()`.

You can use Navigation mixin if you are within a component:
https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/master/docs/api/mixins/Navigation.md

Or if you want to navigate at a place outside of a component (say inside stores) you can use this example:
https://github.com/rackt/react-router/issues/380. Basically you need to:

```
 var AppRouter = React.renderComponent((
     <Routes location="history">
       <Route handler={App}>
       <Route name="login" handler={LoginComponent} path="/login/" />
       </Route>
     </Routes>
 ), document.body)


 // Somewhere else
 AppRouter.transitionTo('foo');
```